# Normal map with color spots

Tags: baking, normal-map

First I scuplted a high-poly model of stylized character. Secondly I did retopology and UV unwrap my low-poly model.
Then I tried to bake from high-poly to low-poly, but my normal map eneded up with color spots.
I also tried a diffent values of extrusion and max ray distance, but it didn't help at all. I make attempt to bake with cage, but it only got worse - almost everything turns green.
Is it possible baking doesn't work because my low-poly slightly bigger than high-poly? Or it can be because of bad retopo?
[image]
[image]

This is my character
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qj3GjZl6hm-oTi9bASXBtVverPu7lXBp/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

- Apply the scale of your low-poly
- Recalculate the normals of your low-poly (they are inverted)
- Choose an *Extrusion* value of 0.1 and a *Maximum Ray Distance* of 0